# Program stays stuck in while loop but doesn't run program?

Tags: python, while-loop

this is a crabs simulator. Im having trouble with my while loop. Where it says

```
while val == True:
```

Is where the problem happens. It stays in the while loop but nothing happens. If you find anything, I will be most grateful.
Here is the full code. (I have tried to validate everything)

```
import time
import random
control1 = False
control2 = True
x = True
val = True
z = True
def throw(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        dice_1 = random.randint(1,6);dice_2 = random.randint(1,6)
        print "roll",i,", die 1 rolled",dice_1,"and die 2 rolled",dice_2,",total",dice_1+dice_2
        time.sleep(2)
    return n

while z == True:
    if x == True:
        while control1 == False:
            try:
                amount_1 = int(raw_input("Welcome to crabs.\nHow many times would you like to roll:"))
                control1 = True
            except ValueError:
                print ("Enter a valid number.")
            throw(amount_1)
            x = False
    else:
        while val == True:
            roll_again = raw_input("Would you like to roll again: ")
            if roll_again == "1":
                val = False
                while control2 == True:
                    try:
                        amount_2 = int(raw_input("How many times would you like to roll:"))
                        control2 = False
                    except ValueError:
                        print ("Enter a valid number.")
                    throw(amount_2)
                    z = True
            elif roll_again == "2":
                val = False
                exit()
            else:
                val = True
```

Comment: `while z == True` may become `while z` because it's the same. No need to 'double check' a boolean ;) You should also give your variables explicit names...

Comment: To help with debugging, why not do a simple `print` in each of the `if` branches?

Comment: Your final else: val = True is not required as val is already true within the while val: Whenyou say that it does not do anything, do you mean that you do not see the prompt for the raw_input commands?

Answer (score 2):

After your first run through the program `x` and `val` are both `False`, but `z` is still `True`. As a result, the outer loop just keeps on rolling.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line:

```
print z, x, val
```

Underneath that while statement.

You'll see that after you respond to the "Would you like to roll again: " question with "2", both `x` and `val` are false. That means that it'll go through every part of your if..else statement and just keep looping back infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

It's stuck in an endless loop after the else branch (of `if x`) is executed, because you set the value to False. In the next iteration you then say `while val == True` and since this statement is not False and there is **no** other statement to consider, you run in an endless loop.

To see what I mean simply add a print statment here:

```
else:
    print val
    while val == True:
        roll_again = raw_input("Would you like to roll again: ")
        if roll_again == "1":
```

Now, I don't know if you need all those booleans for your actual program, but if I'd to make it work, I'd start eliminating the booleans I don't need. I think you have a too complex structure.

**Edit**:
Here's a suggestion to make the program simpler.

```
import time
import random
x = True
z = True
def throw(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        dice_1 = random.randint(1,6);dice_2 = random.randint(1,6)
        print "roll",i,", die 1 rolled",dice_1,"and die 2     rolled",dice_2,",total",dice_1+dice_2
        time.sleep(2)
    return n


def ask(x):
    if x: 
        print "Welcome to crabs."
    try:
        amount = int(raw_input("How many times would you like to roll:"))
    except ValueError:
        print ("Enter a valid number.")
    throw(amount)

while z:
    ask(x)
    x = False
    roll_again = raw_input("Would you like to roll again: ")
    if roll_again == "1":
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: You're welcome. Just make sure to accept an answer if your question was answered.